# Increase php memory_limit using Magento 2 index.php

Tags: magento2, php, memory

I added the line `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` into the `pub/index.php` and reloaded the **Nginx** config, however, the memory_limit didn't change.

I created a phpinfo.php and the memory_limit1 is still showing 768M...

Cleared `/var` and `pub/static` but still not luck.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the memory_limit using the `php.ini` file:

You must find where your php.ini file is, you can easily do that typing `php --ini`

Personally I have it in:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/etc/
```

Then you open the file using `nano`, `vi` or `vim`:

```
vi /opt/plesk/php/7.0/etc/php.ini
```

Inside the file typing `/` you can search inside. Search for `memory_limit`

Once you find it, change the value and exit typing: `:x`.

Hope you achieve it.

Comment: I have other websites on my stack and this would change the `memory_limit` for all the sites?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "stack", but what I can assure is that all Magentos using that php.ini file will suffer the changes from it.
Example: If you have 3 diferent Stores under the same domain: dom1.domain.com, dom2.domain.com, dom3.domain.com, they will all have those changes.

Comment: By "stack" I meant all the other websites using this file... and this is not something I am looking forward to... thank you for your help tho!

Comment: Well, in case you only have 1 store in a server and you need it, it is pretty useful :D I'll have a look if there is another way to do it then.

Comment: There must be some kind of "per domain" Nginx config wrapper. I'll dig it out ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open `vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

`php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 10000M ;` 128M

Then restart php-fpm:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Please try this

Comment: `bash: vim: command not found` error on console.

Comment: try vi or nano instead of vim, you might not have vim installed

Comment: `nano` worked, however it tried to create a new file, meaning it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bare Feet Sorry to late response . please review this https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers worked, you can also configure PHP settings in the Nginx configuration file for your site.

For example, Magento 2 comes with a default Nginx virtual host configuration file, `nginx.conf.sample`, which sets the memory_limit to 768M.

This snippet comes from that file:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";

    # Change the memory_limit value to whatever is appropriate for your site:
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=4096M \n max_execution_time=18000";

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

The above extract sets the memory_limit to 4096M (4GB). You'll need to include it within the server block of your virtual host and this only applies to PHP-FPM.

Comment: Tried your solution but get duplicate errors as such: `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_connect_timeout" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:8` and changing the configuration in the main config file is not something I am willing to do...

Comment: @BareFeet You should modify the snippet to suit your circumstances. If `fastcgi_connect_timeout` is already defined, then don't include it in your virtual host config file.

Answer (score -1):

for apache2 you can change the memory limit in `src/pub/.htaccess`

just be sure ot change it for your php version (5 or 7)

Comment: I am using NginX so `.htaccess` will to reflect any changes...

Comment: true. I never really used nginx so I didn't know they don't use htaccess.